# Read geo-spatial data in R via Leaflet

Tags: gdal, r, polygon, leaflet, rgdal

I have some site boundary data as follow:

```
UNB_BDSB_SiBdry_v08_201028lico_25831.cpq
UNB_BDSB_SiBdry_v08_201028lico_25831.dbf
UNB_BDSB_SiBdry_v08_201028lico_25831.prj
UNB_BDSB_SiBdry_v08_201028lico_25831.sbn
UNB_BDSB_SiBdry_v08_201028lico_25831.sbx
UNB_BDSB_SiBdry_v08_201028lico_25831.shp
UNB_BDSB_SiBdry_v08_201028lico_25831.shp.xml
UNB_BDSB_SiBdry_v08_201028lico_25831.shx
```

Reading those is `R` via `rgdal` package:

```
myfile = readOGR(dsn = dsn
                 layer = "UNB_BDSB_SiBdry_v08_201028lico_25831")
```

I'm getting a warning:

```
OGR data source with driver: ESRI Shapefile 
Source: dsn, layer: "UNB_BDSB_SiBdry_v08_201028lico_25831"
with 1 features
It has 4 fields
Warning message:
In OGRSpatialRef(dsn, layer, morphFromESRI = morphFromESRI, dumpSRS = dumpSRS,  :
  Discarded datum European_Terrestrial_Reference_System_1989 in Proj4 definition: +proj=utm +zone=31 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
```

And the data looks like:

```
head(myfile@data)
            NAME                              GISFILE SHAPE_Leng SHAPE_Area
0 Norfolk Boreas UNB_BDSB_SiBdry_v08_201028lico_25831   90513.37  442457610
```

Now if I use the `addpolygons` function from leaflet, I can not see any added polygon!

```
leaflet::leaflet(data = myfile) %>% addTiles() %>%
addPolygons(
            fillColor = "green",
            highlight = highlightOptions(color = "red", weight = 5,
                                         fillOpacity = 0.7,
                                         bringToFront = TRUE))
```

I'm wondering if there is something wrong with the data or I am doing something wrong!

Also the result using the `st_read` function from the `sf` package is as follow :

```
sf_data = st_read(dsn = "\\\\sv52hcn8934.corp.vattenfall.com/bgf93$/Documents/Map/220420_AH_BdyShp",
+         layer = "UNB_BDSB_SiBdry_v08_201028lico_25831")


summary(sf_data)
     NAME             GISFILE            SHAPE_Leng      SHAPE_Area                 geometry
 Length:1           Length:1           Min.   :90513   Min.   :442457610   POLYGON      :1  
 Class :character   Class :character   1st Qu.:90513   1st Qu.:442457610   epsg:25831   :0  
 Mode  :character   Mode  :character   Median :90513   Median :442457610   +proj=utm ...:0  
                                       Mean   :90513   Mean   :442457610                    
                                       3rd Qu.:90513   3rd Qu.:442457610                    
                                       Max.   :90513   Max.   :442457610
```

Comment: Can you share the data? Can you use the `sf` package and function `st_read` to read the shapefile, and show us the summary or the normal print value of the object?

Comment: @Spacedman, thanks for the reply, the result of using `sf` package added to the question !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a sample sp-class points data frame in a projected coordinate system like your data is:

```
> ps
class       : SpatialPointsDataFrame 
features    : 4 
extent      : 1, 4, 1, 4  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs         : +proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +units=m +no_defs 
variables   : 0
```

If I view it in leaflet, its not in the right place...

```
> leaflet(ps) %>% addTiles() %>% addMarkers()
```

and leaflet doesn't complain. But if I convert it to an `sf` spatial data frame and use leaflet:

```
> leaflet(st_as_sf(ps)) %>% addTiles() %>% addMarkers()
Warning messages:
1: sf layer is not long-lat data 
2: sf layer has inconsistent datum (+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +units=m +no_defs).
Need '+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84'
```

...I get those warnings. This is telling me that `leaflet` needs data in lat-long coordinates, so I can transform them to coordinate system 4326:

```
> leaflet(st_transform(st_as_sf(ps),4326)) %>% addTiles() %>% addMarkers()
```

and that gets me the points in the right place with no errors.

I don't know why `leaflet` doesn't warn with an `sp` class object but does with the equivalent `sf` object - its another good argument for dropping `sp` objects and using `sf` as much as possible.

Comment: `st_transform(st_as_sf(sf_data),4326)
Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 4 fields
Geometry type: POLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 2.75969 ymin: 52.95313 xmax: 3.112287 ymax: 53.24133
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
            NAME                              GISFILE SHAPE_Leng SHAPE_Area                       geometry
1 Norfolk Boreas UNB_BDSB_SiBdry_v08_201028lico_25831   90513.37  442457610 POLYGON ((3.058682 53.24133...`

Comment: `leaflet(st_transform(sf_data,4326)) %>% addTiles() %>% addMarkers()
Error in pointData.default(sanitize_sf(obj)) : 
  Don't know how to get location data from object of class sfc_POLYGON,sfc`

Comment: I still get the error from leaflet and the error is appearing by adding the `addMarkers()` function, but if I remove that I will just get an empty map.

Comment: I'm only using `addMarkers` because my test data is points. Use `addPolygons` for your polygons.